# get string between two texts in XSLT

Tags: xslt, substring

My xml file is like this:

```
<node1>
this is the text of '{$\{titel_mn\}}' in the {$\{subtitle_mn\}} manual > {$\{manual_name
\}}
</node1>
```

I want get the text between `{$\{` and `\}}` and replace the text with some other text from other xml file.

I wrote code like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="externalxmlFile" select="document(concat('./test/material', '.xml'))"/>

<xsl:variable name="replacebleText" select="$externalxmlFile//test[@id=XXXXXXX]/value"/>
```

XXXXXXX should be titel_mn, subtitle_mn, manual_name.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which version of XSLT is it?

Comment: it is in the XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `xsl:analyze-string`. In each case, `regex-group(1)` will return the name of the variable (titel_mn, subtitle_mn, et cetera).

```
<xsl:template match="node1">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\{{\$\\\{{([a-z_]+)\\\}}\}}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="$externalxmlFile//test[@id=regex-group(1)]/value"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, to escape curly braces, you have to double them and prefix them with `\`.

Comment: if my xml file is like this:                                                                                     <node1>
this is the text of '{$\{titel_mn\}}' in the {?\{subtitle_mn\}} manual > {$\{manual_name
\}}                                                                                                              I want get the text between {$\{ and \}}  and {?\{ and \}} and replace the text with some other text from other xml file.
</node1>                                                                                             How can I achieve this?